# Need ajax button to send/retrieve data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm following tutorials for the purpose of creating a table with separate submit buttons for each row. Don't question it, it's what I want to do.

I want the script to return a value to my function, which will then display a message to the user (either a popup, or else perhaps adding to a `<div id="messages">` or something like that.

All the buttons will send data to the same PHP script. I figured I would model this after the jeditable plugin, which submits the element's id to the script.

But I've never written any of my own jquery, so I'm running into problems. My first test

My current test script $(this).id is not working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".magic_button").click(function() {
        var data = $(this).id;
        alert (data); // test
        $("#messages")
                // trying to submit the data and retrieve response
            .load('/myscrpt.php','id=' + data); 
    });
});
```

The test html:

```
<div id="magic_button_form">
<form name="magic">
    <input type="button" class="magic_button" name="magic_button" id="magic_button_1" value="magic" />
    <input type="button" class="magic_button" name="magic_button" id="magic_button_2" value="magic" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="messages"></div>
```

So, basically, I need to figure out how to get the id out of the calling element, submit it by ajax, then handle returned data. It's not working because first of all I can't even get the id of the calling button.

EDIT:

> **Complete, Working Script Per Martin's Answer:**

Per Martin's solution, here is what I came up with in my test and it works. Below is the html/jquery, and then the php script. The php script just does a simple text transformation, changing "magic_button_1" into "Magic Button 1" (and same for any other button of class "button").

Here is basically the html/jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    });
    $(".magic_button").click(function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert (data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/controllers/clean/ajax/table.php",
            data: { 'id': data }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
    });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="magic_button_form">
<form name="magic">
   <!-- <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>  
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />  
    <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label> -->
    <input type="button" class="magic_button" name="magic_button" id="magic_button_1" value="magic" />
    <input type="button" class="magic_button" name="magic_button" id="magic_button_2" value="magic" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php script (/controllers/clean/ajax/table.php)

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$id = ucwords(implode(' ',explode('_',$id)));

echo $id;
```

Comment: There are some misunderstandings of jQuery in your code. I'd suggest you start the right way, that is at the [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). If you just copy/paste, that's bad habit and you probably won't learn anything new like that, seriously.

Comment: Hmm, well I've learned a lot by standing on the shoulders of giants. I think, personally, what helps me stay enthusiastic is when I can actually get something to work at all. That gives me the energy to actually learn why and build on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

[`Here`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is the documentation for jQuery ajax calls, example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.php",
   data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
   alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! $(this).attr('id') works. I'll try the rest. I was following a tutorial that was using .html().load() Is that old/bad code or just another style?

Comment: `.load()` is fine when the intention is to put the response directly into some element. Once you fix the id issue it will work.

Comment: It's usually used for loading simple markup like a popup, the one I posted above is just more flexible and cleaner. Particularly for passing data and receiving a result (particularly if you want to start using JSON for more comprehensive responses).

Comment: Yes I was going to ask about the JSON. I guess that's the standard format for ajax calls?

Comment: There is no standard format for Ajax. If the response is a data structure that will be manipulated by JavaScript then JSON is the best choice. Even something simple such as including both a status code and a message in the response is easiest done with JSON. But if the response is to be displayed directly to the user and no manipulation is necessary then HTML is the best choice. It may be that the server is already setup to return XML, in which case that's easy enough to work with in jQuery too.

Comment: Given that he's working with jQuery I think it's safe to assume the data structure will be manipulated by JavaScript ;)

Comment: I probably want the server to just return the data in a simple structure, then have the script handle various display options. Thanks @nnnnnn.

Comment: @Martin I see you have "name" and "location" not in quotes in data. I assume that is a mistake. I changed that and the test worked perfectly. I'll post my scripts in my question in case it helps anyone.

Comment: @ButtleButkus It was directly from the jQuery documentation, and no it isn't a mistake. It's not required for keys, but I would recommend you do so. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Martin. I'm also finding out that the standard way to return data from a called script is simply with "echo". Is that correct? It worked in this case. The message was properly displayed.

Comment: You probably want to use `echo json_encode(array('success' => true, ....));` ... You can then just check if (result.success) {...} in your JS.

Answer (score 2):

Within your click handler `this` is a reference to the DOM element itself, so you can access its id with:

```
this.id
```

Or, if you want to use jQuery you have to use a jQuery method:

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

Also I notice that your alert references `dataString` but that should probably be `data`.

With those issues fixed the Ajax `.load()` should work.